# Update columns of sqlite3 database in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sqlite

I am new to OSX App development.I am trying to store 4 values (Date, value1, value2, value3) in sqlite databse. I need to update the last 3 fields of a record if a new record is entered with the existing date. How can i do it. My code to insert into database is given below

```
- (void) addToDatabase:(Day *)sampleDay
{
  databasePath = [Database_Access createDirectory];

  const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

  if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    char *errMsg;


    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TABLEOBJ (DATE,NIDHIN,PAI,RUBEN ) VALUES ('%@',%li,%li,%li)", sampleDay.date, sampleDay.value1, sampleDay.value2, sampleDay.value3];

    const char *sql_stmt = [str UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {

    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

  } 
  else 
  {

  }
}
```

What all are to be included in order to meet this requirement?

Comment: So iOS or OS X? Your title says iOS, the question and the tags suggest OS X. Also, what **precisely** is not working with regards to the code you have currently? Furhtermore, what kind of "requirements" do you have?

Comment: You are storing date as text or dateTime object?

Comment: i am storing date as text in database

Comment: then you can go with the solution from @Anusha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check the date already exist or not

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &quizDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        // ================Read date with current date value table===================
        NSString *readDate = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM TABLEOBJ WHERE DATE = %@",sampleDay.date];

        const char *readDate_stmt = [readDate UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(quizDB, readDate_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *str;

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TABLEOBJ (DATE,NIDHIN,PAI,RUBEN ) VALUES ('%@',%li,%li,%li)", sampleDay.date, sampleDay.value1, sampleDay.value2, sampleDay.value3];
            }
            else
            {
                 str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE TABLEOBJ SET NIDHIN = %li, PAI = %li, RUBEN = %li where DATE = %@", sampleDay.value1, sampleDay.value2, sampleDay.value3,sampleDay.date]; 
            }

            // Do the execution steps
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }
```